# Running npx in WSL Ubuntu gives a CMD.EXE and UNC error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, npx

I am running `make` in a directory which runs `npx tailwindcss -i ./static/src/input.css -o ./static/dist/css/output.css` but unfortunately I get the error as below

```
jbob@macbook:~/temmplate/src$ make
npx tailwindcss -i ./static/src/input.css -o ./static/dist/css/output.css
'\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\jbob\template\src'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
Specified input file ./static/src/input.css does not exist.
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 9
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

I have looked at other questions of a similar ilk but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `node` and therefore `npx` installed on the host Windows system and it was trying to reference that instead of the copy installed on Ubuntu

Uninstalled it on Windows and it started working

Comment: This solution worked for me. Uninstalled node from windows then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. this happened because of a NVM misconfiguration. follow these steps to fix.

- check `node -v` on WSL terminal. command wouldn't work.
- check installed node versions by `nvm ls`. see `default -> N/A`? this is the issue.
- bind a node version to default by `nvm alias default <node_version>`
- check `nvm ls` again to see if it's added.
- check `node -v` again. now it'll work(if not check on a new terminal window)